# Kotlin - array list - how to remove all elements of type T if there is less then two

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have an mutable list in kotlin that looks like this:

val groceries = listOf(
Food("orange", "fruit"),
Food("potato", "vegetable"),
Food("banana", "fruit"),
Food("apple", "fruit"),
Food("cucumber", "vegetable"),
Food("salad", "vegetable")
)

i have defined a sealed class so that i can group this data:

```
sealed class RecyclerItem {
    data class Food(val name: String): RecyclerItem()
    data class Section(val title: String): RecyclerItem()
}
```

Where section would be things like "vegetable" or "fruit"
and food would be like "banana" or "apple"
etc etc

to group my data into a single list i have written this code using groupby:

```
val sectionedGroceries: List<RecyclerItem> = groceries
            .groupBy { it.category }
            .flatMap { (category, foods) ->
                listOf<RecyclerItem>(RecyclerItem.Section(category)) + foods.map { RecyclerItem.Food(it.name) }
            }
```

in the end if i print the list it looks like this:

```
[Section(title=fruit), Food(name=orange), Food(name=banana), Food(name=apple),  Section(title=vegetable), Food(name=potato), Food(name=cucumber), Food(name=salad)]
```

but now my issue is if there is ONLY ONE Section in the list i want to remove it such that the list would have only Food in it.  how can i do this most efficiently?

update sorry here is the full code:

```
    class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val groceries = listOf(
            Food("orange", "fruit"),
            Food("potato", "vegetable"),
            Food("banana", "fruit"),
            Food("apple", "fruit"),
            Food("cucumber", "vegetable"),
            Food("salad", "vegetable")
        )

            val sectionedGroceries: List<RecyclerItem> = groceries
                .groupBy { it.category }
                .flatMap { (category, foods) ->
                    listOf<RecyclerItem>(RecyclerItem.Section(category)) + foods }

        Log.v("TAG","$sectionedGroceries")
    }
}


sealed class RecyclerItem {
    data class Food(val name: String, val category: String): RecyclerItem()
    data class Section(val title: String): RecyclerItem()
}
```

Comment: `Food` has only one parameter in your sealed class but in groceries list has two.
And where is `category` defined?

Comment: i updated the code so its very clear now.  i pasted the full code. i just want to remove all the section data classes from the final results if there is only one section  because one section is pointless for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val sectionedGroceries: List<RecyclerItem> = groceries
    .groupBy { it.category }
    .let {
        if (it.size == 1) it.values.first()
        else it.flatMap { (category, foods) ->
            listOf(RecyclerItem.Section(category)) + foods
        }
    }
```

Comment: the let statement was my issue, i kept thinking it was an rxjava stream when its not. its kotlin functions.. thanks !